# Second Order partial differential equation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following equation:
$$
\begin{align} 
 &\Theta \big[-\sin\psi \sin\gamma \sin\theta g- \frac{\cos\psi}{\sin\theta} \sin\gamma \frac{\partial g}{\partial \phi}+
\\
&(\cos\gamma+\cot\theta\sin\gamma\cos\psi)\frac{\partial g}{\partial \psi}  \big] \nonumber \\
& +   \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial\phi^2} + \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta}\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial\psi^2}  -\frac{2\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial \phi \partial\psi}  =0
 \end{align}
$$

where $\Theta$ is a positive constant, $\gamma$ is fixed angle and $g=g(\phi,\psi)$ where both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are in $[0,2\pi]$ $\theta\in(0,\pi)$. Is there any way to obtain an analytical solution. I appreciate any help.

Comment: As a first simplification, you can factor $\exp(\cos(\theta))$ out,

Comment: @ user159517, Then what would be the appropriate method to use to solve the equation.

Comment: I really dont know of any general techniques to analytically resolve equations like this. By the way, dont you have boundary conditions or initial conditions?

Comment: one thing you can always try is to make an ansatz separating the variables, but I dont know to what that will lead in this case.

Comment: @user159517. Not obvious how to use separation method, but I am thinking of  perturbation technique [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020746298000857). I have never heard of this technique but I would appreciate if someone help me understanding this method.

Comment: I proposed an edit to your question, maybe we can get some more attention on this question that way. If not, I'll propose a bounty as soon as it is possible.